# Determine the paper size of a djvu document

Tags: djvu

How can I determine the paper size of a djvu document? I tried it with both DjView and Evince, but did not find any mention of the paper size. I wouldn't mind using some CLI tool, but I don't have a clue what to use.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think DjVu has the specific concept of a page size, but you can determine document sizes by looking at the image sizes and their resolutions. `djvudump`, from [DjVuLibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/), will output information such as

```
    FORM:DJVU [52780] {Gaffiot-0001.jpg.djvu} [P1]
      INFO [10]         DjVu 1666x2708, v24, 300 dpi, gamma=2.2
      Sjbz [52750]      JB2 bilevel data
    FORM:DJVU [56019] {Gaffiot-0002.jpg.djvu} [P2]
      INFO [10]         DjVu 1700x2708, v24, 300 dpi, gamma=2.2
      Sjbz [55989]      JB2 bilevel data
```

Each `FORM:DJVU` tag is a page, and here we have two pages of different sizes: 1666×2708 at 300 dpi is 141×229 mm, 1700×2708 is 144×229 mm.